# Gráfico de interação no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Estou tentando adaptar alguns gráficos padrão do R para o estilo do `ggplot2`. Um dos gráficos para o qual pretendo fazer isto é o gráfico de interação em um estudo de ajuste de modelos lineares.

Os dados a seguir foram retirados do Exemplo 9-1 do livro Design and Analysis of Experiments, do Douglas C. Montgomery, 6ª Edição.

```
montgomery <- structure(list(Nozzle = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
"A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", 
"A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", 
"A3", "A3", "A3", "A3"), Speed = c("B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", 
"B3", "B3", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B2", 
"B2", "B2", "B2", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B3", 
"B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3"), Pressure = c("C1", "C1", "C2", 
"C2", "C3", "C3", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C3", "C3", "C1", "C1", 
"C2", "C2", "C3", "C3", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C3", "C3", "C1", 
"C1", "C2", "C2", "C3", "C3", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C3", "C3", 
"C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C3", "C3", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C3", 
"C3", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C3", "C3"), Loss = c(-35, -25, 
110, 75, 4, 5, -45, -60, -10, 30, -40, -30, -40, 15, 80, 54, 
31, 36, 17, 24, 55, 120, -23, -5, -65, -58, -55, -44, -64, -62, 
20, 4, 110, 44, -20, -31, -39, -35, 90, 113, -30, -55, -55, -67, 
-28, -26, -62, -52, 15, -30, 110, 135, 54, 4)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -54L), .Names = c("Nozzle", 
"Speed", "Pressure", "Loss"))
```

De acordo com a maneira tradicional de criar o gráfico que desejo, eu preciso rodar

```
interaction.plot(montgomery$Nozzle, montgomery$Speed, montgomery$Loss)
```

[image: Gráfico de Interação Tradicional]

Eu consigo criar um gráfico similar usando `ggplot2`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

interaction <- montgomery %>%
  select(Nozzle, Speed, Loss) %>%
  group_by(Nozzle, Speed) %>%
  summarise(Average = mean(Loss))

ggplot(interaction, aes(x=Nozzle, y=Average, colour=Speed, group=Speed)) + 
geom_line()
```

[image: Gráfico de Interação com ggplot2]

O que eu desejo agora é criar uma função chamada `interaction.plot.ggplot2` que faça automaticamente o gráfico anterior. O problema é que não sei como chamar as colunas para os comandos do `dplyr` para fazer a preparação dos dados a serem plotados.

```
interaction.plot.ggplot2 <- function(response, predictor, group, data){

    interaction <- data %>%
      select(predictor, group, response) %>%
      group_by(predictor, group) %>%
      summarise(average = mean(response))

    p <- ggplot(interaction, aes(x=predictor, y=average, colour=group, group=group)) + 
    geom_line()

    print(p)
}

interaction.plot.ggplot2(Loss, Nozzle, Speed, montgomery)

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Nozzle' not found
```

O que devo fazer para que minha função `interaction.plot.ggplot2` crie o gráfico que desejo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fazer programas em que as variáveis variam com o `dplyr` e com o `ggplot` pode ser muito chato.

Aqui vai uma função que funciona para o que você quer:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lazyeval)

interaction.plot.ggplot2 <- function(response, predictor, group, data){

  l_response <- lazy(response)
  l_predictor <- lazy(predictor)
  l_group <- lazy(group)

  interaction <- data %>%
    select_(.dots = list(l_predictor, l_group, l_response)) %>%
     group_by_(.dots = list(l_predictor, l_group)) %>%
     summarise_(
       .dots = setNames(list(interp(~mean(response), response = l_response)), "average")
       )

  p <- ggplot(interaction, aes_string(x=expr_text(predictor), y="average", colour=expr_text(group), group=expr_text(group))) +
    geom_line()

  print(p)
}


interaction.plot.ggplot2(Loss, Nozzle, Speed, montgomery)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tudo isso está razoavelmente bem descrito nesses links:

- [Non-standard evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html)
- [Lazyeval](https://rpubs.com/hadley/lazyeval)

---

Para aceitar nomes de variáveis sem aspas ex: `select(data, nome_var)`, o dplyr usa o que é chamado de *lazy evaluation* ou *non-standard evaluation*. Ela é assim chamada pois usualmente o R *calcula/avalia* os argumentos das funções antes de utilizá-los dentro da função.

Por exemplo:

```
myfun <- function(x){
  return(x)
}
myfun(x = 1 + 1)
[1] 2
```

*lazy-evaluation* é uma forma de atrasar a avaliação do argumento, de forma a tornar possível de capturar a expressão que o usuário digitou como argumento da função.

```
myfun <- function(x){
  return(lazy(x))
}
myfun(x = 1 + 1)
<lazy>
  expr: 1 + 1
  env:  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Essa forma de programar permite o *non-standard scoping* que é muito útil para fazer programas para análises de dados de forma interativa. O trade-off é a complexidade do código quando a análise não é interativa (por exemplo o seu problema).

Deixo aqui o trecho relevante do abordagem do lazyeval:

> Non-standard scoping (NSS) is an important part of R because it makes
>   it easy to write functions tailored for interactive data exploration.
>   These functions require less typing, at the cost of some ambiguity and
>   “magic”. This is a good trade-off for interactive data exploration
>   because you want to get ideas out of your head and into the computer
>   as quickly as possible. If a function does make a bad guess, you’ll
>   spot it quickly because you’re working interactively.

Ressalto que para entender bem, vale muito a pena ler [esse documento](https://rpubs.com/hadley/lazyeval)

Comment: Excelente resposta, Daniel. Eu desconhecia este conceito de *lazyeval*.